# java calendar ui

Tags: java, calendar

I am trying to create a calendar ui that can embed in my html web page. I want the user to be able to add events and have them show up on the calendar and have them be color coded based on what category of event it is. Any ideas regarding to which direction I should start heading?

Comment: I have a suspicion that you mean JavaScript?

Comment: @Corbin You can indeed build fine web app user-interfaces using pure Java that are automatically rendered in web-standards technologies: [Vaadin](http://www.Vaadin.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend [gwt-cal](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-cal/)

It's easy to embed GWT widgets into any HTML page and has the features you need.

Answer (score 0):

http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/views/

This is a good place to start

It is built on JavaScript . But it can be integrated with your java web server

Answer (score 0):

## Vaadin Calendar

For Java, use the [Calendar widget](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/components/components-calendar.html) found in [Vaadin](http://www.Vaadin.com/). See [demo](http://demo.vaadin.com/sampler/#ui/data-input/dates/dates-calendar).

[image]

[image]

## Vaadin date-picker

By the way, Vaadin also offers a date-picker widget. See [this demo](http://demo.vaadin.com/sampler/#ui/data-input/dates/date-picker). See [Tutorial](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/components/components-datefield.html).

Available independently as a [Polymer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymer_(library))-based [Web Component](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Components) from the [Vaadin Elements](https://vaadin.com/elements) project as the [vaadin-date-picker](https://vaadin.com/elements/-/element/vaadin-date-picker).

Check back later on the Vaadin Elements project. They plan to add more components. Perhaps the they well offer a full calendar widget in the future.